# Swift for Android: `ld` cannot find `-lgcc` in swift for android compilation linking step

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, gcc, android

I'm trying to compile Swift code on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, following [these instructions](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/Android.md) fairly closely. I was able to download the NDK r14 okay, download the libicu tools and build them, and download the swift source and build that against the libicu tools. I get all the way down to compiling actual swift code and get this:

```
#build.sh 
#(I symlinked the androideabi ld.gold to /usr/bin/ld.armv7, based on a swift bug ticket's advice. Thats the only thing different from the instructions)

/home/mike/workspace/swift-source/build/Ninja-ReleaseAssert/swift-linux-x86_64/bin/swiftc \
-use-ld=armv7 \
-tools-directory /home/mike/workspace/android-ndk-r14/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/arm-linux-androideabi/bin \
-target armv7-none-linux-androideabi \
-sdk /home/mike/workspace/android-ndk-r14/platforms/android-21/arch-arm \
-L /home/mike/workspace/android-ndk-r14/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a \
-L /home/mike/workspace/android-ndk-r14/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9 \
hello.swift


#output
mike@mike-VirtualBox:~/workspace/HelloSwift$ ./build.sh 
/usr/bin/ld.armv7: error: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld.armv7: error: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld.armv7: error: cannot find -lgcc
/usr/bin/ld.armv7: error: cannot find -lgcc
```

I don't have a ton of experience being this far down the toolchain, but I definitely have gcc installed, and gcc-multilib, and LD_LIBRARY_PATH set to help ld find gcc, and I've rebuild the ld cache with ldconfig.

Comment: What does `sudo /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep libgcc` return?

Comment: `libgccpp.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgccpp.so.1`

`libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6,x32) => /usr/libx32/libgcc_s.so.1`

`libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1`

`libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still wondering, at some point I had managed to move one of the binaries or rename one of the directories somehow, something small like `linux-x86-64` to `linux-x64-64`